# My application works only on Heroku without https

Tags: facebook, security, heroku, https

My new application is hosted on heroku. I noticed that it works fine on heroku without https. But when i try it on facebook it doesn't work.

What's going on ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you be more precise ? What "doesn't work" ? Do you get any error message ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have "Secure Browsing" turned on in your facebook settings

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security

Comment: That's true. I have desactivated it and now the app works. But how about the other visitors who want to use it? i guess most of them have this option activated. is here any solution? how to make my app working even secure browsing is on ? thanks

Comment: @Nadjib Amari Within the facebook settings there is an option for Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL. The secure canvas url is required and this ensures that the app will work even when secure browsing is turned on.